# Edit Time from a DateTime variable in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, datagrid

I have a datagrid with the following column

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MorningCheckOut, StringFormat=t">
```

With the way its setup it works well to display the data I need.
f.e : 8:00 AM

The problem comes when I'm editing it, since when I change the time, the DateTime variable updates the date to `DateTime.Now`.

Any suggestions on how to deal with this problem?

Comment: Take a look at the following similar question and the comment and the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54941186/datagrid-datetime-ivalueconverter-edit-time-only-preserve-date

Comment: wouldnt work for me @mm8, i have the converter in 4 columns, it would be really hacky if anything, i found a better solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by having a reference DateTime inside my model then doing:

```
public DateTime MorningCheckOut
    {
        get => _morningCheckOut;
        set
        {
            if (value == _morningCheckOut) return;
            _morningCheckOut = new DateTime(Day.Year, Day.Month, Day.Day, value.Hour, value.Minute, value.Second);               
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```